# InvalidCastException from very simple linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

EDIT:  Nevermind.  The sample below is adapted from C# converted from legacy VB code that has pairs of structures and classes with same name.  So "KooClass" below is actually a structure and KooArray returns array of the class class.

Would like to just delete this question but no such option it seems.

==================================================
The first query works fine.  The second linq throws InvalidCastException.

this.HooArray is a property that returns an array of HooStruct.  Likewise KooArray is a property that returns an array of KooClass.

I have stepped through the get of both array properties, and they return without problem.

As you can guess by the names, HooStruct is a stucture, KooClass is a class.

What is going on here?

```
        var goo = (from Foo.Goo.HooStruct g in this.HooArray
                   select g).ToList();

        var foo = (from Foo.Goo.KooClass g in this.KooArray
                   select gt).ToList();
```

Comment: what is "gt"? should that be g?

Comment: We'd need to see the declaration of KooArray and KooClass to be able to give you any concrete info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like KooArray contains objects that are not KooClass objects

Comment: If the solution isn't as simple as that, then re-write your code using old-fashioned programming (without linq) and hopefully the solution will become evident

Comment: it was that simple, or simpler... I have made the same mistake working with the VB version of this code (and VS autocompletion getting confused) and then not seeing it for quite some time.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to close out this question.